# ApexPage error message not displaying

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages

I have a custom visualforce page that has to display an error if some data is failed to retrieved and though I can see the `ApexPages.addMessage(message)` method being called it doesn't work

This is my apex controller (now forced to display the error):

```
public List<SelectOption> getData(){
  List<SelectOption> result = new List<SelectOption>();
  /** retrieve data code **/
  ApexPages.Message message = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'TESTING');
  ApexPages.addMessage(message)
  return result;
}
```

And this is my VFP:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="MyController">
  <!-- rest of code -->
  <apex:pageMessages escape="false" id="messages"></apex:pageMessages>
  <!-- rest of code -->
  <apex:selectList id="selInv" value="{!dataSel}" multiselect="false" size="1" label="Select data"> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!data}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
  <!-- rest of code -->
</apex:page>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or implementing in the wrong way?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce is not updating live, so to display a message the page or component needs to be re-rendered.
When loading the list of select options, the error component is already rendered so it does not updates automatically. Here is an example, where the error works:

Visualforce Controller:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="SEController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageMessages id="messages"></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:selectList id="selInv" value="{!dataSel}" multiselect="false" size="1" label="Select data" > 
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!data}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="messages"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>   
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class SEController {
    
    public Case c {get;set;}
    public String[] dataSel {get; set;}
    
    public SEController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        c = new Case();
        ApexPages.Message message = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'TESTING Beginning');
        ApexPages.addMessage(message);   // this prints the message on the page load
    }
    
    public List<SelectOption> getData(){
        List<SelectOption> result = new List<SelectOption>();        
        ApexPages.Message message = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'TESTING Middle');
        ApexPages.addMessage(message); // this does not print the message
        return result;
    }
    
    public void save() {
        ApexPages.Message message = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'TESTING Button');
        ApexPages.addMessage(message); // this prints the message on button click
    }
}
```

In summary, the easiest option is to move the data generation part to the constructor to avoid playing around with some Java Script hacks that could help you achieve the re-render.